# Stored Procedure is taking very long to complete

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures

We have a `csv` file with 2000 rows and a database `table1` about 2 million rows and another `table2` with 60000 rows.

We need to query from `table1` based on parameters from the csv file, so each row in `csv` should execute one select query. Initially we tried to execute the following query within a `for loop` in the application:

```
SELECT table1.c1, 
       table1.c2, 
       ST_Distance_Sphere(point(csv.c2[i], csv.c3[i]), 
       point(table1.c3, table1.c4)) * 0.2 AS length, 
       table1.c5 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  table1.c1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT table2.c1 
                     FROM      table2 
                     LEFT JOIN table2.c1=table3.c1 
                     WHERE table2.c2=1 
                     AND   table2.c3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000) 
HAVING length < csv.c4[i] 
AND    table1.c5 BETWEEN date("start_date") AND date("end_date") 
ORDER BY table.c1
```

the `csv.c1[i]` `i` is actually the loop index. Because of the 2000 round trips to MySQL server, it takes a long time to complete this. It takes about 16 hours just to get through the queries.

So, I wrote the SP below to avoid looping and simply call this SP so can do the looping in MySQL server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp() 
    BEGIN 
      DECLARE arg0 VARCHAR(255);
      DECLARE arg1 FLOAT;
      DECLARE arg2 FLOAT;
      DECLARE arg3 FLOAT;
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM csv_based_table;
      OPEN cur1; 
      read_loop: LOOP
         FETCH cur1 INTO arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3;
         SELECT col0, 
                col1, 
                ST_Distance_Sphere(point(arg1, arg2),point(col3,col4))*2 AS length, 
                arg0 
         FROM   important_table1 
         WHERE  col0 IN (SELECT DISTINCT c0 
                         FROM   important_table2 
                         LEFT JOIN table3 
                         ON col0 = c0 
                         WHERE c1=1 
                         and c2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000) 
         HAVING distance < arg3 
         AND col5 BETWEEN date("start_date") AND date("end_date") 
         ORDER BY arg0, col0;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur1;
    END;
```

So, instead of using the csv file, we create a database table for that csv file and run the above stored procedure. Problem is this turned out to be slower than the original 2000 iterations loop. In a test over 100 csv rows, for loop-based original solution finished in **317.6 seconds** while the stored procedure took **321.5 seconds** just for the SP itself. Why is this happening and how can I optimize this?

Comment: It is hard to help when we can't see what column is in what table, for example:  `WHERE c1=1`

Comment: That's about a 1% difference -- not significant.  What is means is that CSV vs CROSS JOIN is not the main part of the inefficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one suggestion:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE csv
( i int not null
, c1 ... not null
, c2 ... not null
, c3 ... not null
, c4 ... not null )
```

Load the csv file into the temporary table, and use a join to get the result.

```
SELECT csv.i 
   table1.c1, 
   table1.c2, 
   csv.st_dist_spere, 
   ST_Distance_Sphere(point(csv.c2[i], csv.c3[i]),  
                      point(table1.c3, table1.c4)) * 0.2 AS length, 
   table1.c5 
FROM   table1
CROSS JOIN csv  
WHERE  table1.c1 IN (
                 SELECT DISTINCT table2.c1 
                 FROM      table2 
                 LEFT JOIN table2.c1=table3.c1 
                 WHERE table2.c2=1 
                 AND   table2.c3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
HAVING length < csv.c4 
   AND    table1.c5 BETWEEN date(start_date) AND date(end_date) 
ORDER BY csv.i, table.c1
```

I would then look at the `IN` predicate (I'll assume this is what it is supposed to be):

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.c1 
FROM      table2 
LEFT JOIN table3
    ON table2.c1=table3.c1 
WHERE table2.c2=1 
  AND table2.c3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

The outer join against table3 can be eliminated (a smart optimizer should realize this, but I don't know if this is implemented in MySQL):

```
SELECT DISTINCT table2.c1 
FROM      table2 
WHERE table2.c2=1 
  AND table2.c3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

This leaves us with:

```
SELECT csv.i 
   table1.c1, 
   table1.c2, 
   csv.st_dist_spere, 
   ST_Distance_Sphere(point(csv.c2[i], csv.c3[i]),  
                      point(table1.c3, table1.c4)) * 0.2 AS length, 
   table1.c5 
FROM   table1
CROSS JOIN csv  
WHERE  table1.c1 IN (
                 SELECT DISTINCT table2.c1 
                 FROM      table2 
                 WHERE table2.c2=1 
                 AND   table2.c3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
       )
HAVING length < csv.c4 
   AND    table1.c5 BETWEEN date(start_date) AND date(end_date) 
ORDER BY csv.i, table.c1
```

Next step, is trying to replace the `IN PREDICATE` with a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT csv.i 
   table1.c1, 
   table1.c2, 
   csv.st_dist_spere, 
   ST_Distance_Sphere(point(csv.c2[i], csv.c3[i]),  
                      point(table1.c3, table1.c4)) * 0.2 AS length, 
   table1.c5 
FROM   table1
CROSS JOIN csv  
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT table2.c1 
       FROM      table2 
       WHERE table2.c2=1 
       AND   table2.c3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
     ) as X
   ON X.c1 = table1.c1
HAVING length < csv.c4 
   AND    table1.c5 BETWEEN date(start_date) AND date(end_date) 
ORDER BY csv.i, table.c1
```

It may be advantageous to push the range predicate into table1 before doing the cross join:

```
SELECT csv.i 
   table1.c1, 
   table1.c2, 
   csv.st_dist_spere, 
   ST_Distance_Sphere(point(csv.c2[i], csv.c3[i]),  
                      point(table1.c3, table1.c4)) * 0.2 AS length, 
   table1.c5 
FROM (  
    select ... from table1 
    where table1.c5 BETWEEN date(start_date) AND date(end_date)
) as table1
CROSS JOIN csv  
[....]
```

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake, the LEFT JOIN in the inner SELECT was with a third table.

Comment: I have at least 17 million rows in table 1 before any filtering and 2000 rows in csv. Will the cross join produce something very big? This is safe to do?

Comment: You can push the predicates into table1 before the join

Answer (score 2):

(Lennart covers some issues; I'll cover some others.)

16 hours is not bad for performing *trillions* of operations.

**Turn the inefficient `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a derived table.**

```
table1.c1 IN ( SELECT DISTINCT table2.c1 
                 FROM      table2 
                 LEFT JOIN table2.c1=table3.c1 
                 WHERE table2.c2=1 
                 AND   table2.c3 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000 )
```

-->

```
JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT c1 FROM table2
                 WHERE c2 = 1 AND c3 BETWEEN ... ) AS x
    ON x.c1 = table1.c1
```

(Lennart explains most of why.)  Also, depending on what version you are using, the INner `SELECT` may be repeated for each row of c1.

**Add some `INDEXes`.  This should significantly decrease the 4 billion computations.**

Details:
have the composite `INDEX(c2, c3)` -- in that order.  Also, `INDEX(c1)` on `table1`.

It's not just 2000 round trips, it's 2000*2M "rows" involved.  That's 4 billion!

Move this out of `HAVING` and into `WHERE`:

```
AND    table1.c5 BETWEEN date("start_date") AND date("end_date")
```

and have `INDEX(c5)` on `table1`.  Doing this should cut down the 2M (hence, the 4B) rows by some amount.  If `"start_date"` is not a literal, but rather a column in some table, then we have a another problem.

**Consider a 'bounding box'.**

I'm guessing you are trying to list which of 2M items are "close" to 2K items.

One way to help (but not fully optimize) a "find nearest" in a two-dimensional problem is to have a "bounding box" to quickly filter out many of the rows.  I don't know your schema well enough to give you more than a rough idea:

```
SELECT ... AS distance
    WHERE lat BETWEEN 12.345 AND 13.579
      AND lng BETWEEN 45.678 AND 47.474
    HAVING distance < ...
```

and then have `INDEX(lat, lng)` and `INDEX(lng, lat)`.  (The optimizer will pick the one that seems better for the data in question.)